# Covariance matrix returns different values

Tags: python, statistics, covariance

I have a data set X and I want to calculate covariance matrix

```
     dataset=pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape(len(image),len(data[1])))
     X = dataset.iloc[:,variables].values
```

The only way I found to calculate it without error was as follows:

```
     V=np.cov(X.astype(float).astype(int),rowvar=False)
```

However, If I calculate

```
     np.var(X[:,0].astype(float))
```

It happens that it is a bit different compared to

```
     V[0,0]
```

I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: Adding a little reproducible example of what you are trying to do would help this post.  Additionally, it doesn't appear to be connected to `pandas` so you might want to disentangle some of the DataFrame stuff to show your example.

Answer (score 0):

I will use iris dataset to demonstrate how you can get equal variances between `np.cov` and `np.var` functions:

```
# load dataset
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data

# calculating var
np.var(X.T, axis=1) # var is calculated using an additional multiplier of  "(n -1) / n"
# output of np.var
array([0.68112222, 0.18871289, 3.09550267, 0.57713289])

# calculating cov
np.cov(X.T)
# output of np.cov
array([[ 0.68569351, -0.042434  ,  1.27431544,  0.51627069],
       [-0.042434  ,  0.18997942, -0.32965638, -0.12163937],
       [ 1.27431544, -0.32965638,  3.11627785,  1.2956094 ],
       [ 0.51627069, -0.12163937,  1.2956094 ,  0.58100626]])
# variances are different

# correct the variance in np.var to get the same as in np.cov
n = X.shape[0]
np.var(X.T, axis=1)* (n / (n-1))
# output of corrected np.var
array([0.68569351, 0.18997942, 3.11627785, 0.58100626])
```

So, the difference was in this multiplier `n / (n -1)` where `n` is number of observations.

I hope it will help you somehow